# Como usar .append hidediv para ocultar um campo zoom do formulário

Tags: javascript, append, zoom

É um formulario no Fluig e esse campo que quero ocultar é um campo zoom que busca um dataset, ele fica aparecendo na primeira atividade sendo que usei o appen para ocultar o mesmo mas ainda assim aparece

**Append que estou usando para esconder o campo no formulario.**

```
.append('$(\'*[name="causa"]\').css(\'display\', \'none\');var closers = $(\'*[name="causa"]\').closest(\'.form-field\').find(\'input, textarea, select\');var hideDiv = true;$.each(closers, function(i, close) {if (close.style.display != \'none\' && close.type != \'hidden\') {hideDiv = false;}});if (hideDiv == true) {$(\'*[name="causa"]\').closest(\'.form-field\').css(\'display\', \'none\');}');
        customHTML.append('</script>');
        customHTML.append('<script>');
        customHTML
                .append('$(\'*[name="causa"]\').closest("li").hide()');
        customHTML.append('</script>');     
    }
```

**Esse é o meu campo zoom no formulario:**

```
<div>  
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-12">
                    <b> Causa do Chamado: </b> 
                    <input type="zoom" class="form-control" id="causa" name="causa"
                        data-zoom="{
                            'datasetId':'_xlsGetCausaTI',
                            'displayKey':'des_causa',
                            'placeholder':'',
                            'fields':[
                                {
                                   'field':'des_causa',
                                   'label':'Selecione a Causa'
                                }
                                ]
                            }"  />
                       
                        </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Atualizei ali, obrigado pela dica.

Answer (score -1):

Fiz um

````
var activity = getValue('WKNumState');
    
    if (activity == 3 || activity == 0) {
        form.setVisibleById("div_causa", false)
        form.setVisibleById("div_aprdes", false)
        form.setVisibleById("div_usertxt", false)
        form.setVisibleById("div_prioridadesolic", false)

``` e resolveu.
````

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).